# WCF async calls throwing Target invocation exception in Main()

Tags: .net, wcf, asynchronous, exception

I' developing a WCF client which makes Asynchronous calls to the WCF server. I'm using .NET 3.5 with Winforms. My original method is named GetPoints() and I'm using the GetPointsAsync() from the proxy generated by the visual studio 2010 to call the service.

So far everything was working nicely but the problem comes when the server throws a fault exception.
The exception arises in the Main() method --> Application.Run(new Form1()) as "Target invocation exception" :(

I tried a synchronous method and the exception arises correctly where it should, so the problem is not in the server.
Also I've tried to find the InnerException but there is none. In fact I cannot even find the targetInvocationException.
As far as I understand, the exception should arise in the client_GetPointsCompleted() method, isn't it ?
Is there something else I should take into account ?
Where did the exception go ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception should be in the `Error` property of the `GetPointsCompletedEventArgs` instance passed to the `client_GetPointsCompleted` event handler.

Comment: Thanks, but why is it rising in the Main()?

Comment: Could you please tell me where can I find some sample code of exception handling for this async pattern? I've been googling but I cannot find any information on that matter.

Comment: Take a look at the InnerException property in the TargetInvocationException, it should give you more information on this issue.

Comment: I found information in there, thanks! So, is it a rule that exceptions will come inside InnerException when using this async calls?

Comment: Not for async calls, but for `TargetInvocationException`. Take a look at the remarks in the MSDN documentation for this class - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.targetinvocationexception.aspx

Comment: I've implemented a code which checks for the error property in GetPointsCompletedEventArgs, and if =! null throws it. It works perfect ! Thank you for the help.